How to run an Xcode app via the terminal?
On simple IDE's in Windows and/or Linux, when you build/compile a .cpp file, you end up with an executable for Windows that you can run via DOS by typing the filename.exe or, when in Linux, you use the terminal and ./filename to run the binary.
I have been kindly given an old-ish Mac ...
When in Mac and Xcode, I end up only with the .cpp file and nothing to run via the terminal. I know that Xcode has an output mini window at the bottom sort of emulating the whole process,
but I want to learn and test my lessons/code via the terminal. So what am I missing? Where is the executable?
Excuse my lack of knowledge but I guess everyone has to start somewhere...


If you want to use the terminal then don't use Xcode.  Instead use vscode/zed/clion/neovim along with cmake.

Xcode makes finding the executable file more difficult than it needs to be. In Xcode choose Product > Show Build Folder in Finder.
Go to the Finder. There should be a window open for the Build folder. Inside this folder is a Products folder. Navigate the Products folder to find the executable file. Double-click the executable file to run the program in the Terminal.
